# How to splice the last characters of a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, split

I'm trying to extract the text of a URL without the pesky numbers in the way so this:

```
array = ['123/john-doe', '45336/jane-doe']
```

would turn into this

```
array = ['john-doe', 'jane-doe']
```

Heres' what I got so far:

```
array = ['123/john-doe', '45336/jane-doe']

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
 var tabId = array.slice("/").pop();
    console.log(tabId)

 }
```

I can get it to work with one ID just fine:

```
name = "123/john-doe"

var tabId = name.split("/").pop();
console.log(tabId)
```

Outputs:

```
john-doe
```

Can someone help me out with putting this into a for loop? Thanks!

Comment: You don't use the `i`.

Comment: `.slice("/")` doesn't make sense. Your next example uses `.split("/")`. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
array = array.map(function(item) {
    return item.split('/').pop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = ['123/john-doe', '45336/jane-doe']

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     var tabId = array[i].split("/").pop();
        console.log(tabId)

}
```

Adding the array[i] unpacked the array and outputted:

```
john-doe
jane-doe
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var array = ['123/john-doe', '45336/jane-doe'];
array.map(function(s) {
    return s.replace(/^\d+\//, '');
}); // [ "john-doe", "jane-doe" ]
```